# fgets() initializes variables on its own

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

I am working on a bit of code that wants to read data from a file, parse this data and store each word of the file in a array of chars. Then, I want to use this array to compare it to a string read from a separate file - this part you won't need to see below.

Something very funny is happening with my data and I have been looking for the answer without success. Here is a reduced and simplified version of the code (excuse some of the variables' names, in French) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define maximum 200000

//  CODE

typedef unsigned idx;
typedef char * str;
typedef enum {False, True} bool;

#define max_mots 200000                             
char *mots[max_mots];                               
idx mot_libre = 0;                                  

#define max_refs 16                                 
idx refs[max_mots][max_refs];                       
idx ref_libre[max_mots];                            

void usage(str message) 
{   
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message); 
    exit(1); 
}

str stoplist[max_mots];

void indexe(str ligne, idx ref)                     
{
    printf("stoplist %p: %s\n", &stoplist, *stoplist);
    printf("ligne %p: %s\n", &ligne, ligne);    
}

int main(int argc, const str argv[]) 
{
    int i = 0;
    if (argc < 2) usage("manque le nom du fichier...");
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-s") == 0){
        FILE * stop = fopen(argv[3], "r");          
        if (! stop) usage("fichier non conforme...");
        char liste[max_mots];
        fgets(liste, maximum, stop);
        str buffer = strtok(liste, " ");
        while (buffer != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            stoplist[i] = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, " "); 
            i++;
        }
        fclose(stop);
    } 
    char ligne[maximum];                            
    printf("ligne %p :%s\n", &ligne, ligne);
    FILE * flux = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (! flux) { 
        usage("wrong file"); 
    }
    idx x = 0
    while (fgets(ligne, maximum, flux))         
        indexe(ligne, ++x);                             
    fclose(flux);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is meant to be executed with the following format:

```
[name of the executable] [name of a text file to read from] -s [name of another text file to read from]
```

The first text file can be something like:

```
hi, I am coding in C.
```

And the second could be:

```
am I in
```

What the code will intend to do is store every word in the **stoplist** pointer on a array of char from the second text file, and store the whole string of the first text file to the **ligne** array.

Return after execution of the code:

```
am
I
in

ligne [whatever address it has] : am // WHY?! I have not initialized you with this at any point in the code!
stoplist [whatever address it has] : Hi, I am coding in C. // Should be "am"

ligne [whatever address it has] : Hi, I am coding in C.
```

When I call fgets() again to assign the string **Hi, I am coding in C** to **ligne**, both **ligne** and **stoplist** will be updated to this new value! Literally have no idea why. Both variables have different addresses, and as you can see in the code, the input used has a different name too ; both reading sessions are closed the right way.

Any ideas? I know that's something to do with them pointing on something similar, but I can't understand why and where...

Comment: Purely stylistically speaking, please don't put spaces before semicolons `;` or commas `,` — it isn't the way it's done in idiomatic C.  There should usually be a space after a comma.  In a `for` loop, there should be a space after a semicolon; otherwise, semicolons should usually be followed by a newline.  And don't scrunch an `if` test and its action onto a single line; it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler noted, I will edit the style. Thanks for taking the time correcting beginners!

Comment: Please provide the code that fails as the code that is in the question.  You don't currently read anything from the second file.  You don't check that the `fgets()` worked on the first file.  This makes it hard to know exactly what you're testing.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It makes life easier in the long run.  At the moment, you're not using `split_chars` or `sl_default`; they should not be in the MCVE.  Also, please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  One of the key techniques I use is printing inputs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is an MCVE. The fgets() does not need to be tested in order to see the issue: the printf() display the issue in the return you'll get given you use the code, the files content provided, and the arguments.
What you see is that the variable **ligne** get initialized with a similar content than **stoplist** without the code actually asking for it to happen. This is where the problem stems from. More than necessary debug printing attempts are shown in the code and highlight the issue I have.

Comment: In the lines `char ligne[maximum]; printf("ligne %p :%s\n", &ligne, ligne);`, the printing of the data tries to print uninitialized memory.  That is UB — undefined behaviour.  There is no point in speculating why an uninitialized variable contains any given value; there is no requirement that it contain any specific value.  Anything is valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler okay, I get that now. Surprising, but valid. As explained in the original post, calling fgets() the second time in the quoted while loop will replace the content of **stoplist** with the one that this fgets() read from the file, the **Hi, I am coding in C.** string, I have edited my original post for you to see the full execution and problem.

Comment: `typedef char * str;` Please don't hide pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: First potential UB: `FILE * stop = fopen(argv[3], "r");` - `argv[3]` can be `NULL` here.

Comment: @melpomene yes, it can; this is why I specified the format to use with all the arguments necessary in order to run the code. The return I posted is coherent with the initial data and command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `stoplist` is initialized:

```
stoplist[i] = buffer;
```

`buffer` is from here:

```
str buffer = strtok(liste, " ");
```

`liste` is a local variable in the first block:

```
char liste[max_mots];
```

In other words, `stoplist` stores pointers into `liste`, but by the time you examine the contents of `stoplist`, `liste` is already gone (local variables are destroyed at the end of their block). This is known as "dangling pointers".

Your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! That is a very helpful answer. Will look into the dangling pointers and hopefully solve it today!